# Is "doubt" a stative verb

Tags: stative-verbs

The worst thing “is doubting” yourself. Is the use of this verb phrase “is doubting” correct? Many grammar books say “doubt” is a stative verb and cannot be used in the progressive form but I have found it being used in progressive form very often including news from BBC, CNN, the Guardian, etc. Any advice?

Comment: Without commenting on its status as a staive verb, I should tell you that your example sentence proves nothing either way. 'Doubting' is a gerund there, not a progressive verb.

Comment: There are many Google hits for "was doubting", and the vast majority seem to be the participle usage. Verbs often have both punctive / inchoative and durative usages.